OpenSSL does not copy email to SubjectAltName
I configured OpenSSL through its openssl.cnf file to copy subjectAltName from the email, e.i., subjectAltName = email:copy. Yet, when I come to sign the CSR, I see that the subject alternative name field is empty, as shown below:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                <EMPTY>

The other thing that I noticed is that the email is not present anywhere in the certificate, although it IS present in the CSR.
How can I configure OpenSSL to copy the subjectAltName from the email?

Apparently, OpenSSL CLI tool attributes the email to the Subject Alt Name by not specifying what value to attribute to the SAN. Yes, I simply commented that extension from the profile, i.e.,
    #subjectAltName     = email:copy

The, when I tried to sign it, it was printed:
            X509v3 Issuer Alternative Name: 
                email:example@example.com

And when I tried to print it, it was also printed:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                email:it@alboutica.dz

